# Do-While Loop Java Output Error

Tags: java, powershell, java-8, windows-7-x64, do-while

I'm working through "Java a Beginner's Guide, Sixth Edition" by Herbert Schildt.

Using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit with Java 1.8.0_73 in Windows Powershell.

When I compile this exercise (no compiler warnings or errors whatsoever):

```
class DoWhileDemo {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    throws java.io.IOException {
        char ch;

        do {
            System.out.print( "Press a key followed by ENTER: " );
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
        } while( ch != 'q' );
    }
}
```

When I run it with 'java DoWhileDemo' I get

```
Press a key followed by ENTER: f
Press a key followed by ENTER: Press a key followed by ENTER: Press a key followed by ENTER: q
```

The program exits as expected (when I hit 'q' and press ENTER), but the multiple printings of "Press a key followed ENTER: " are not.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
ch = (char) System.in.read();
```

reads in a *single* character.  When a user presses `q` and `enter`, three characters get sent to your code:

```
q
\r
\n
```

on a Windows system.  So you get two more paasses through the loop before there's nothing in the input queue and your code stops reading.

On Linux you would see only one extra prompt as in that case only two characters get sent (`q\n`).

If you want to process entire lines (as it appears you do), you must wrap `System.in` in a `BufferedReader` so you can call `readLine()`.

Comment: Funny, you answered the same thing on the duplicate question ;).

Comment: 18 months ago... I didn't remember that one :-)

Answer (score -1):

This is because when you press `f` that means it is not equal to `q` so condition is true and loop execute again and again when you press `q` condition becomes false and loops exits

Comment: This is misleading. And try to avoid posting such misleading answer _after_ it's closed as duplicate of a much better answer...